# ngx-datatable mouse hover rendering issue

Tags: angular, mouseevent, render, ngx-datatable

I am using Ngx-datatable with Angular. 
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable

Its loading data without any problems.

The problem I have is ngx-datadatable is rendering whenever I move the mouse pointer over data rows.

Is there anyway I can disable it ?

Comment: Have you got any fixes? Coz I am also stuck in the same

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this bug too.
my solution was pretty simple,
just add this into `datatable.component.ts`:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

you may want to check if they didn't solve this in latest versions.